# AWS Lex doesn't pick up user response from pressing responseCard button on facebook

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services

On the test bot in the AWS console, I can type out the utterances and the responses to each slot, and AWS Lex picks it up. But on Facebook Messenger, where I have set up response cards with their corresponding text and values, clicking on a button from a response card doesn't seem to reach Lex.

I use Lambda functions to dynamically create the response cards, and it looks something like this:

```
{
  "dialogAction": {
    "type": "ElicitSlot",
    "intentName": "ShopIntent",
    "slots": {
        "product": null,
        "category": null
    },
    "slotToElicit": "category",
    "message": {
        "contentType": "PlainText",
        "content": "Choose a category."
    },
    "responseCard": {
        "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
        "version": 1,
        "genericAttachments": [
            {
                "title": "New",
                "subTitle": "All the new things!",
                "buttons": [{
                    "text": "New",
                    "value": "1234567890"
                 }]
            }, {
                "title": "Shurts",
                "subTitle": "A collection of shirts!",
                "buttons": [{
                    "text": "Shurts",
                    "value": "1234567891"
                }]
            }, {
                "title": "Shuus",
                "subTitle": "A collection of shoes!",
                "buttons": [{
                    "text": "Shuus",
                    "value": "1234567892"
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

This renders correctly in Facebook. But on clicking the button, nothing happens. The typing indicator appears for a few seconds (much longer than a request should take -- I wonder if this indicates some error?), then vanishes without giving any response. *It doesn't even create any entry in the CloudWatch log*. I've checked the documentation and I believe, to the best of my knowledge, that format of the `responseCard` is correct.

I don't know how to debug this issue. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was just that I had not ticked the `messaging_postbacks` webhook in the Messenger settings of my Facebook app. With that and `messages` both checked, I can finally interact with the lex bot as desired.